# How to store all the form posted data in asp.net dictionary

Tags: c#

I am using c# as code behind.

I have got lots of values which is been posted when my FORM is submitted, below are few of them:

```
skywardsNumber  99999039t
password    a2222222
ctl00$MainContent$ctl22$FlightSchedules1$ddlDepartureAirport-suggest    Alice Springs (ASP)
ctl00$MainContent$ctl22$ctl07$txtPromoCode  ManojPromo
```

Now I want to store all the FORM posted values in the asp.net dictionary and then that dictionary object will be saved in **SESSIONS** for further use.

Please suggest how can I store the **FORM POSTED** values in **asp.net DICTIONARY**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
...

Dictionary<string, string> form = new Dictionary<string, string>(from key in Request.Form.AllKeys select new DictionaryEntry(key, Request.Form[key]));
Session["MyKey"] = form;
```

**UPDATE**

Without LINQ:

```
Dictionary<string, string> form = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
    form.Add(key, Request.Form[key]);
Session["MyKey"] = form;
```

Comment: I don't have Linq, I am using .NET 2.0, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following.

```
Request["varaibleName"];
```

or to loop through

```
 foreach ( string var in Request.Form ) {
     Response.Write ( Request.Form[ var ] );
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I can get it using above code, I want some loop of FORM Data and from where I can read all the FORM posted values and also how to store in dictionary and then dictionary object in session.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class that implements IDictionary :

```
public class RequestDictionary : IDictionary<string, string>
{


    private HttpRequest request;
    public RequestDictionary(HttpRequest request)
    {
        this.request = request;
    }


    public string this[string key] {
        get { return request(key); }
        set {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

You can then create an RequestDictionary object from you request and use it like a dictionary, without copying all you values in a new dictionary.